# Google Sheet Formula to find longest chain of incrementing values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data like below and what I'm hoping to get:

Data table for copying:

| values |
| --- |
| 21 |
| 76 |
| 23 |
| 24 |
| 25 |
| 26 |
| 62 |
| 63 |
| 47 |
| 30 |
| 31 |
| 32 |
| 45 |

| Expected Output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 1 |

where 1 is for the values that don't have an incremented value in cell under, 4 represents the chain from 23->26 (each row being incremented by 1), etc.

Essentially I want to get the length of each sequence. I'm not too sure how to do it, I've been able to get a `TRUE` and `FALSE` array with a simple formula like:

```
=A2=A3-1
```

which gives a very rough idea where the number of sequential trues values are 1 less than the longest length but also isn't the clearest for false values since you'd need to skip the false values right after a chain and just made it more complicated when I was thinking of using it in an ArrayFormula with Frequency.
I wasn't able to get anything that worked.

Any help or ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how output is `4` for data `23` and `2` for the data `24`?

Comment: @Harun24hr sorry I wasn't sure how to show the expected output but essentially it is mapping the length of each chain so the 4 is actually because of the chain 23->26, 2 would be for 62->63, the 1s for those that don't have an incremented number after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values are in the range `A2:A14`, here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a,A2:A14,
       TOCOL(
         LEN(
           SPLIT(
             REGEXREPLACE(
                JOIN(,N(a+1=OFFSET(a,1,0))),
                "1+0|0",
                "|$0|"),
             "|")))))
```

[image]

This formula is creating a string of 1s and 0s depending on whether the next value is 1 + the previous value or not, then it uses `SPLIT` and `REGEXREPLACE` to divide the string into the appropriate substrings and `LEN` to check the length of these substrings.

**Note**: This formula as it currently is will not work if you have more than 50k values in the range, however this problem can be easily addressed if required.

### EDIT - Formula that works with open ranges ignoring blank cells

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a,TOCOL(A2:A,1),
       QUERY(
         TOCOL(
           LEN(
             SPLIT(
               REGEXREPLACE(
                 JOIN(,N({"";a+1}={a;""})),
                  "1+0|0",
                  "|$0|"),
             "|"))),
         "offset 1",)))
```

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, if there is a blank cell in the range A2:A14 is there a way to handle that (in my case I'd want to just ignore it)

Comment: @JackieJones, I edited the answer with the updated formula that handles that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have to look into this more but it works wonders!